# Make it easy to start tomcat instances on Mac

Tags: macos, tomcat

I have two tomcat servers installed, at the locations:

```
/Users/alexstaveley/developer/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
/Users/alexstaveley/developer/servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.42
```

To start them, I am opening a terminal CDing the right bin directory and then doing

```
sh catalina.sh start
```

This is getting cumbersome.  I'd much prefer to have something on my doc or desktop and then just click the instance I want to start.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

If you rename the `*.sh` files to `*.command`, you can just doubleclick them (I don't have a Mac to double-check, you might need to `chmod +x` them).

If you want the shell to open, just create a file `startTomcat.command` with `sh catalina.sh start` as its sole content

Answer (score 1):

- After installing tomcat rename the folder to tomcat and place that tomcat folder under Macintosh HD -> Users -> alexstaveley directory
- Change the tomcat->bin->startup.sh file, open startup.sh in textedit, add the following 2 lines after EXECUTABLE=catalina.sh line

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Home
  export CATALINA_HOME=/Users/user/Tomcat**
  ```
- Finally to start tomcat, open Mac Terminal

  ```
  cd /Users/alexstaveley/tomcat/bin 
  sh startup.sh
  ```